# segmentation fault in function returning pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I wrote a program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *sqrt(int a[10]);
int main()
{
    int a[10],i,*b;
    printf("enter your integers \n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            scanf("%d",a+i);
    b=sqrt(a[10]);
    printf("the modulus of this values are\n");

            printf("%d",*(b));
    return 0;
}
int *sqrt(int x[10])// function
{
    int *c,i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
            x[i]=x[i]*x[i];
    }
    c=x;
    return p;
}
```

The code gives me a segmentation fault after I enter the values. What mistake have I made here?

Comment: Please turn on your compiler's warning, and ask yourself: where am I assigning a value to `p`?

Comment: What is the significance of `p` in the code?

Comment: Your code is quite a mess. You should learn how to use arrays first. That might be a problem.

Comment: Square Root? Modulus? Power to 2? What actually are you after? :-S

Comment: Also the code as shown won't compile. Should `return p;` probably read ` return c;`?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the 11<sup>th</sup> element to `sqrt()`:

```
b = sqrt(a[10]);
```

You want to pass the address of the 1st element:

```
b = sqrt(&a[0]);
```

or even more straight forward:

```
b = sqrt(a);
```

Using the construct above the array `a` decays to a pointer to its 1<sup>st</sup> element, which is the same as `&a[0]`.